# How to escape period in ed

Tags: bash, ed

I'm studying the ed text editor.

To exit from input mode, a user should enter a line a single period (`.`).

Let's say I want to enter the period as text.

I thought of a workaround: first, I insert something like `..`. Then, I replace `..` with `.`.

But my approach is little unwieldy. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your approach is fine, it's even suggested by POSIX: _The typical method of entering a single <period> has been to precede it with another character and then use the substitute command to delete that character._ And POSIX also specifies that there are no escape characters in input mode.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't found magic escape sequence.

It seems it doesn't exist.

But [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46111/how-to-write-a-literal-dot-in-ed) offers 2 solutions. First I described in my question. Second one is closer to a solution with escape.

```
r ! echo .
```

Answer (score 6):

Reading through the C source for GNU `ed(1)`, there is no escape character. On the occasions that I've wanted to do this, I tend to add a blank line and then use a quick substitution:

```
a↵
↵
.↵
s/^/.↵
```

or you can add a character then delete it (which, if you're playing `ed(1)` golf), is one character more than above)

```
a↵
x↵
.↵
s/./.↵
```

Comment: For the record, this is also what `diff -e` does. `diff -e <(echo) <(printf '.\n')`